# ShellScript to send Mattermost notification is not working

Tags: bash, shell

I want to send a Message into a Mattermost channel with the help of a ShellScript/WebHook/cURL. The following code is the function to send the Message.

```
function matterSend() {
ENDPOINT=https://url.to.Mattermost/WebhookID
USERNAME="${USER}"
PAYLOAD=$(cat <<'EOF'
'payload={
"username" : "${USERNAME}",
"channel" : "TestChannel",
"text" : "#### Test to \n
| TestR     | TestS       | New Mode                               |
|:-----------|:-----------:|-----------------------------------------------:|
| ${2}       | ${3}        | ${1} :white_check_mark:            |
"
}'
EOF
)

  echo "CURL: curl -i -X POST -d ${PAYLOAD} ${ENDPOINT}"
  curl -i -X POST -d "${PAYLOAD}" "${ENDPOINT}"
}
```

As you can see, when I ECHO the command I get:

```
curl -i -X POST -d 'payload={
"username" : "TestUser",
"channel" : "TestChannel",
"text" : "#### Test to \n
| TestR     | TestS       | New Mode                               |
|:-----------|:-----------:|-----------------------------------------------:|
| ${2}       | ${3}        | ${1} :white_check_mark:            |
"
 }' https://url.to.Mattermost/WebhookID
```

If I paste that code directly into the terminal and execute it, it works. But when I run the script with the help of a Jenkins-Job I get the Error:

> Unable to parse incoming data","message":"Unable to parse incoming
>   data".

Why is it not working?

Comment: Hmmm, I'm confused as to why you even have a good result when you echo the command. Quotting the heredoc delimiter prevents variable expansion, so the string `${USERNAME}` is sent as is, without substitution from your local shell

Comment: Yes you are right. I have already tried many different ways and none worked properly. In this way, it is actually the case that the values ​​are not replaced. Didn't noticed that. But at the moment it is not my main problem :-(

Comment: The single quotes *in* the here document certainly look suspicious, too.

Comment: As an aside -- avoid the `function` keyword in `function funcname() {`; the POSIX-standard syntax is just `funcname() {`, and the ksh syntax that the `function` keyword is taken from doesn't use the `()` (and bash doesn't support the special behavior of that syntax anyhow; in ksh, using `function` made variables local-by-default). See http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowledge of the API you are connecting to, I would guess that you need

```
# Drop function keyword, indent body
matterSend() {
  # Lowercase variable names; declare them local
  local endpoint=https://url.to.Mattermost/WebhookID
  local username=$USER
  # Pro tip: don't use a variable for the payload if it's effectively static
  payload=$(cat <<-__EOF
    payload={
    "username" : "$username",
    "channel" : "TestChannel",
    "text" : "#### Test to \\n| TestR     | TestS       | New Mode                               |\\n|:-----------|:-----------:|-----------------------------------------------:|\\n| ${2}       | ${3}        | ${1} :white_check_mark:            |\\n"
    }
__EOF
  )

  echo "CURL: curl -i -X POST -d $payload $endpoint"
  curl -i -X POST -d "$payload" "$endpoint"
}
```

Replacing the newlines inside the `"text"` element with `\n` (and doubling the backslash because the here document is now being interpreted by the shell when it's assigned) is mildly speculative; perhaps remove the remaining newlines, too.  The real beef is removing the misplaced literal single quotes around the payload.

Maybe also explore `printf` for formatting fixed-width tabular text.

The here document's `<<-__EOF` uses the unquoted separator `__EOF` and the dash before it says to remove any tabs from the beginning of each line. Needless to say, the indentation on those lines consists of a literal tab character.

Comment: with a few little adaptions to the payloud text, it worked.
What also worked was removing the single quotes this was also a problem.
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Generating JSON (or XML, or other structured formats) via string concatenation leads to pain and suffering. Instead, use a tool that *actually understands the format*.

Using a compliant generator such as [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) means you no longer need to be responsible for putting `\n`s in the data (as multi-character strings), changing `"`s in text to `\"`, or any of the other otherwise-necessary munging.

```
matterSend() {
  # Lowercase variable names; declare them local
  local endpoint=https://url.to.Mattermost/WebhookID
  local username=$USER
  local text="#### Test to
| TestR     | TestS       | New Mode                               |
|:-----------|:-----------:|-----------------------------------------------:|
| ${2}       | ${3}        | ${1} :white_check_mark:            |
"
  payload=$(jq --arg username "$username" \
               --arg channel "TestChannel" \
               --arg text "$text" \
               '{"username": $username, "channel": $channel, "text": $text}')

  # Advice: use "set -x" if you want to trace the commands your script would run.
  # ...or at least printf %q, as below; avoids misleading output from echo.
  # printf '%q ' curl -i -X POST -d "$payload" "$endpoint" >&2; echo >&2
  curl -i -X POST -d "$payload" "$endpoint"
}
```